# Conditional and custom validation on Add / Edit form fields when using Kendo grid custom popup editor template

Tags: validation, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-template, kendo-validator

I am using a custom template for kendo grid popup Add / Edit form. Here is my working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/8j0a0xuf/)

I want to implement conditional validation on form fields such as **if any value is entered for Address (not left empty) then the fields City and Postal Code should become required**, otherwise they can be empty. Also I want to ise a custom validation rule for PostCode so that its length should always be equal to 4 else it should show a custom error message as "Postcode must be four digits"

I have referred these links:

[**Validation rules in `datasource.model`**](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.model)

[**Custom validation rules and error messages**](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/validator/overview#application-of-custom-message-attributes)

but I can't figure out how can I implement validations in my datasource model?

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<h3>I want to implement conditional validation on Add/Edit form such as if any value is entered for Address then the fields City and Postal Code should become required</h3>
<div id="grid"></div>
<script id="popup-editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <p>
    <label>Name:<input name="name" required /></label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Age: <input data-role="numerictextbox" name="age" required /></label>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label>Address: <input name="address"/></label>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label>City: <input name="city"/></label>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label>Post Code: <input name="postcode"/></label>
  </p>
</script>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" },
    { command: "edit" }
  ],
  dataSource: {
    data: [
      { id: 1, name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
      { id: 2, name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
    ],
    schema: {
      model: { id: "id" },
      fields: {
        name:{},
        age:{},
        address:{},
        city:{},
        postcode:{},
      },
    }
  },
  editable: {
    mode: "popup",
    template: kendo.template($("#popup-editor").html())
  },
    toolbar: [{ name: 'create', text: 'Add' }]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/839u80x2/) how I implemented it:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script id="popup-editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
<div id="myForm">
  <p>
    <label>Name:<input name="name" required /></label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Age: <input data-role="numerictextbox" name="age" required /></label>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label>Address: <input name="address" id="address"/></label>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label>City: <input name="city" id="city"/></label>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label>Post Code: <input name="postcode" id="postcode"/></label>
    <!--<span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="postcode"></span>-->
  </p>
  </div>
</script>
```

**JS:**

```
var validator;
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" },
    { field: "address" },
    { field: "city" },
    { field: "postcode" },
    { command: "edit" }
  ],
  dataSource: {
    data: [
      { id: 1, name: "Jane Doe", age: 30, address:'Addr', city:"city", postcode: '1234' },
      { id: 2, name: "John Doe", age: 33, address:'Addr11', city:"city11", postcode: '4321' }
    ],
    schema: {
      model: { id: "id" },
      fields: {
        name:{},
        age:{},
        address:{},
        city:{},
        postcode:{},
      },
    }
  },
  editable: {
    mode: "popup",
    template: kendo.template($("#popup-editor").html())
  },
  toolbar: [{ name: 'create', text: 'Add' }],
  save: function(e) {//alert('save clicked');
    if(!validator.validate()) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
  },    
  edit: function(e){
  //alert('edit clicked');
    validator = $("#myForm").kendoValidator({
    messages: {
        postcode: "Please enter a four digit Postal Code"
    },
    rules: {
        postcode: function(input) {
            //console.log(input);
            if (input.is("[name='address']")) 
            {
                if (input.val() != '')
                {
                    $('#city, #postcode').attr('required', 'required');
                    //return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#city, #postcode').removeAttr("required");
                }
            }
            else if (input.is("[name='postcode']")) {
                if ($('#address').val() != '' && input.val().length != 4)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    },
}).data("kendoValidator");
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If i were to do that, i would do these approach where

1. I will create a custom validator
2. Override the edit(grid) function place the validator there
3. Override the save(grid) function use validator.validate() before saving

Here is an example in [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EzaXE)
basically this is the grid code:

```
var validator;  
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" },
    { command: "edit" }
  ],
  dataSource: {
    data: [
      { id: 1, name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
      { id: 2, name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
    ],
    schema: {
      model: { id: "id" },
      fields: {
        name:{},
        age:{},
        address:{},
        city:{},
        postcode:{},
      },
    }
  },
  save: function(e) {
    if(!validator.data("kendoValidator").validate()){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
  },    
  edit: function(){
     validator = $("#test-form").kendoValidator({
      validateOnBlur: false,
      rules: {
        matches: function(input) {

          var requiredIfNotNull = input.data('test');
          // if the `data-test attribute was found`
          if (requiredIfNotNull) {
            // get the input requiredIfNotNull
            var isFilled = $(requiredIfNotNull);

            // trim the values and check them
            if ( $.trim(isFilled.val()) !== "" )  {

              if($.trim(input.val()) !== ""){
                // the fields match
                return true;
                }else{
                return false; 
              }

            } 
            // don't perform any match validation on the input since the requiredIf
            return true;
          }

          // don't perform any match validation on the input
          return true;

        }
      },
      messages: {
        email: "That does not appear to be a valid email address",
        matches: function(input) {
          return input.data("testMsg");
        }
      }
    });
  },
  editable: {
    mode: "popup",
    template: kendo.template($("#popup-editor").html())
  },
    toolbar: [{ name: 'create', text: 'Add' }]
});
```

ps: i used to many if statement, you could simplify it i think

Comment: Thanks for your answer mate it was of great help so an UP for you. But I did not accept it as an answer as it still missed the custom validation for postcode length. Anyway, with a bit of your hints I found my solution. Thanks again :)